# External Monitor display issue when closing the lid of laptop

Tags: laptop, acer-aspire, external-display

Has anyone experienced this with an Acer or any other laptop?

I am working on a new Acer laptop (1810T) which I almost alway connect to an external monitor with a VGA cable.

I have set graphic options to display only to the external monitor and I would like to close the lid of the laptop, when I am working at my desk.   In the power settings, I have set it so when i close the lid, the computer should "do nothing".

When connected to the external monitor I am able to  view the display fine if the the laptop lid is open.   However, whenever I do close the lid, the display on the external monitor continuously cuts in and out about every 2 or 3 seconds.  I have seen other posts where the display simply shuts off, but I am getting constant (though irregular) flashes of the display, so I believe this is a different issue.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue sometimes (sometimes at startup), even in dual display configuration. The external monitor would turn on and off at 1 or 2 seconds period.

Shutting off and on the monitor itself solves the problem for me, have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> will help you to switch back the work to monitor as a normal user even after closing the laptop lid.

Answer (score 0):

Odd. I sometimes work with my laptop lid closed and using the external monitor, and it's never been a problem. Have you tried updating your graphics drivers? Look in Windows Update under optional Hardware Updates, and see if there's anything relating to your graphics drivers. Since it's a new laptop that's probably not the issue, but it's worth trying.

Just out of curiosity, why don't you use both monitors? I've found that having dual displays is extremely helpful.

Comment: I second the dual displays.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Acer, but the following tips helped for my MacBook.

The only way it will work closed is if the power is plugged in - took me a while to realize this.  The other thing is that I had to have an external keyboard plugged in.  Then, when I closed the laptop, my computer went to sleep and then I used the keyboard to wake it up.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer's "help and support" files walk you thru the power saver plans. If that doesn't fix the problem, I'd suggest you return the laptop to your supplier for diagnosis. These days most vendors are quite accommodating due to competition.

I've set up Sony, Toshiba, Acer, and the configurations seem slightly different but using the built in help files I've always been able to get the lid closure function working OK, especially on VGA using the "balanced" power plan and using the laptop's  power adapter.

Answer (score 0):

See if setting the "Max performance" power plan helps. Also I recommend you to get the latest graphics drivers from Acer's website.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I found it was fixed once I set my monitor settings to only display on the external monitor.